# Not able to use filter in observable list of objects using typescript

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

Trying to filter a list of objects in Observable List.

Model:

```
export class Month {
  id: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Values:

description: "January"
id: "01"

description: "February"
id: "02"

description: "March"
id: "03"

In my service is where I try to return a list with the selected value, in this case is just one, but in the future could be more.

```
  selectedMonth: string = "02";
    public getMonths(): Observable<Month[]> {
        return of(this.MONTHS).pipe(
          map(months => {
            months.filter(month => {
              month.id === this.selectedMonth;
            });
            return months;
          })
        );
      }
```

but it seems filter doesn't work at all, I get always the whole list (12 elements, instead of one element)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.monthservice.getMonths().subscribe(months => (this.months = months));

    console.log(this.months);
  }
```

This link has the code:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myfilter?file=src/app/services.ts/month.service.ts
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest form is recommended:

```
public getMonths(): Observable<Month[]> {
    return of(this.MONTHS).pipe(
      map(months => months.filter(month => month.id === this.selectedMonth))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you aren't returning the filtered array, rather the original array.

```
public getMonths(): Observable<Month[]> {
    return of(this.MONTHS).pipe(
      map(months => {
        return months.filter(month => month.id === this.selectedMonth);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my answer as I had forgot to return the filtered months inside `map`. This works now. tried with your StackBlizt setup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is yout map function. Your map function is doing some operation but return no object. you have to return an object:

```
map(months => {
  let filteredM = months.filter(month => {
    month.id === this.selectedMonth;
  });
  return filteredM;
})
```

but the scope of a map function is to change the type of elaborated source, in this case the source and the result have the same type so in this case you can use only filter function without the map.